# How to operate with SQL Query Output

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to do a multiple `SELECT` query taking the `WHERE` argument as the first query output

```
SELECT id FROM hotel where group_id != 1;
```

Output: 1,3,4,5,6,7,9

Now I want to take those IDs (output of the first query) and do multiple `SELECT`s with them

```
SELECT user_id FROM users where hotel_id = [1,3,4,5,6,7,9];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `IN` (with sub-query) instead of `=`:

```
-- ignore hotel_id with NULL using IN with sub-select
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE hotel_id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM hotel 
    WHERE group_id <> 1
);

-- with hotel_id NULL using IN with sub-select
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE hotel_id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM hotel 
    WHERE group_id <> 1
) OR hotel_id IS NULL;
```

Another solution can be the following using a `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`:

```
-- ignore hotel_id with NULL using INNER JOIN
SELECT users.user_id
FROM users INNER JOIN hotel ON users.hotel_id = hotel.id 
WHERE hotel.group_id <> 1

-- with hotel_id NULL using LEFT JOIN
SELECT users.user_id
FROM users LEFT JOIN hotel ON users.hotel_id = hotel.id
WHERE hotel.group_id <> 1 OR users.hotel_id IS NULL;
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43708821ed495dabaf4aec2ec47dcdb2)

Comment: Why an OUTER JOIN (subsequently quietly transformed to an INNER JOIN)?

Comment: You have used an INNER JOIN here. You can prove it by executing `EXPLAIN EXTENDED [YOUR QUERY]` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS`. Your argument rather falls apart in the face of that evidence. :-(

Comment: This is still an INNER JOIN - except now MySQL is no longer smart enough to spot it.